# How can I bind source MediaCapture to CaptureElement without pattern?

Tags: c#, mvvm, windows-phone-8.1

I write application on Windows Phone 8.1. I am using a MVVM without pattern. 
I cannot how I can bind a MediaCapture object to a CaptureElement in the view.
I know that this topi repeated but i try this solutions

my code XAML:

```
<ContentControl HorizontalAlignment="Left"         
Width="320" Height="140" Content="{Binding CaptureElement}"Margin="40,183,0,257"/>
```

in my viewModel:

```
private CaptureElement _captureElement;
public CaptureElement CaptureElement
{
    get
    {
        return _captureElement;
    }

    set 
    { 
        _captureElement = value; OnChange("CaptureElement"); }
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your code is not complete. I'm not sure which problem you really met. Or you just don't know how to write.  I have a complete solution here which can meet your requirements.I have tested it.

**XAML Code**

```
    <ContentControl HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Width="320" Height="140" Content="{Binding CaptureElement}" Margin="40,183,0,257"/>
```

**Code behind in MainPage()**

```
MyViewModel view = new MyViewModel(); this.DataContext = view;
```

**In view mode**

```
class MyViewModel: NotificationBase
{
    private MediaCapture _mediaCapture;
    public MediaCapture MediaCapture
    {
        get
        {
            if (_mediaCapture == null) _mediaCapture = new MediaCapture();
            return _mediaCapture;
        }
        set
        { 
            _mediaCapture = value;
        }
    }
    private CaptureElement _captureElement;
    public CaptureElement CaptureElement
    {
        get
        {
            if (_captureElement == null) _captureElement = new CaptureElement();
            return _captureElement;
        }
        set
        {               
            _captureElement = value;
        }
    }

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        ConfigureMedia();
    }

    private async void ConfigureMedia()
    {
        await MediaCapture.InitializeAsync();
        CaptureElement.Source = MediaCapture;
        await MediaCapture.StartPreviewAsync();
    }

}
```

Also upload this demo [here](https://onedrive.live.com/?authkey=%21AD2al9aB2P8SGs8&id=BFE3BD0E499803F%216140&cid=0BFE3BD0E499803F), you can download for testing.

Comment: thank you so much!
with your help I resolved the issue